# How to create a Dashboard using data pushed in to Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build-process, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-workflow

I am wondering if it is possible to create a dashboard on Jenkins, using the statistics saved in a data sheet we commit/push in each time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin called [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) which can create a chart using files over different builds.

> This plugin provides generic plotting (or graphing) capabilities in
>   Jenkins.
>
> This plugin will plot one or more single values variations across
>   builds in one or more plots. Plots for a particular job (or project)
>   are configured in the job configuration screen, where each field has
>   additional help information. Each plot can have one or more lines
>   (called data series). After each build completes the plots' data
>   series latest values are pulled from Java properties file(s), CSV
>   file(s), or XML file(s) via an XPath (which you should have generated
>   during the build) somewhere below you workspace. Data for each plot is
>   stored in a CSV file within the job's root project directory.
>
> It can generate various kind of plots, including Area, Bar, Line,
>   Stacked Bar, Waterfall...

If you need a different way of displaying data, you could try the [Summary Display Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin) which can also display tables.

Comment: Can Plot plugin also create a table from a data file? Thanks!

Comment: I think not. I've added another plugin to display data in different ways than charts.